# Akka persistance and at least once delivery

Tags: java, akka, akka-persistence

I have some messaging application which needs at-least-once guaranties.
As I understand from documentation: the akka-persistence - is about the actor state. And it uses some layer-by-layer ideology to deal with that state.

In the documentation I found some AbstractPersistentActorWithAtLeastOnceDelivery which seems to be proposing this guaranty. But now I have some doubts about the conception in general:

My actor is a simple transmitter and all I need - is delivery guaranty. So I don't actually care about the actor state and all that layering which consumes precious memory. Can the extensive journal be the reason of problems?

The actor:

```
public class SafeSenderActor extends AbstractPersistentActorWithAtLeastOnceDelivery {

    private String persistenceId;
    private ActorSelection destination;

    public SafeSenderActor() {
        System.out.println("SafeSenderActor created");
        this.persistenceId = "safe-persistent-actor-id-" + UUID.randomUUID();
        destination = context().actorSelection("/user/safeReceiverRouter");
    }

    @Override
    public String persistenceId() {
        return persistenceId;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractActor.Receive createReceive() {
        return ReceiveBuilder.create()
                .match(SenderTaskMessage.class, msg -> {
                    persistAsync(new MsgSentEvent(msg.getTestMessage()), this::updateState);
                })
                .match(ConfirmRobustMessageDelivery.class, ack -> {
                    persistAsync(new MsgConfirmEvent(ack.getMessageId(), ack.getLocalMessageNumber()), this::updateState);
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceiveRecover() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(Object.class, this::updateState).build();
    }

    private void updateState(Object event) {
        if (event instanceof MsgSentEvent) {
            MsgSentEvent ev = (MsgSentEvent) event;
            deliver(destination, deliveryId -> new RobustTestMessage(deliveryId, ev.getMessage()));
        } else if (event instanceof MsgConfirmEvent) {
            MsgConfirmEvent ev = (MsgConfirmEvent) event;
            confirmDelivery(ev.getDeliveryId());
        }
    }

}
```

After some continuous messaging I get the error:

```
[ERROR] [07/06/2017 01:40:33.446] [sender-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-50] [akka://sender-system@127.0.0.1:6666/user/safeSendersRouter/$d] Failed to persist event type [com.test.common.events.MsgSentEvent] with sequence number [358698] for persistenceId [safe-persistent-actor-id-648ec66d-7b7f-4291-b3a2-9bd395d92dc7]. (akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.)
```

I'm using the leveldb as a journal.

Comment: How about just send an acknowledgement message to the sender of a message and resend messages (with a time interval) until the sender receives that acknowledgement? Then just give the message an ID and make sure that the receiving actor does not process the same message twice.

Comment: Also if you don't use clustering and you don't plan to then you don't really need to worry: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#the-rules-for-in-jvm-local-message-sends

Comment: @thwiegan thanks for the advice but currently I need to investigate the Persistence module as a delivery guaranty tool. We are using the akka-remote.

Comment: Even if you use akka remote, first comment still stands. Shouldn't be hard to implement it yourself with a simple acknowledgement message.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long time but maybe it is still useful to answer it. You can override the methods `onPersistFailure` and `onPersistRejected` to investigate the error that you mentioned. The `onPersistFailure` method is called if persisting failed. The actor will be stooped. BEst practice is to start the actor again after a while and use Backoff supervisor. The `onPersistRejected` method is called if the JOURNAl fails to persist the event. The actor is RESUMED.

```
public class SafeSenderActor extends AbstractPersistentActorWithAtLeastOnceDelivery implements ActorLogging {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onPersistFailure(Throwable cause, Object event, long seqNr) {
        log().error("fail to persist $event because of: {}", cause);
        super.onPersistFailure(cause, event, seqNr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPersistRejected(Throwable cause, Object event, long seqNr) {
        log().error("persist rejected for {} because of: {}", event, cause);
        super.onPersistRejected(cause, event, seqNr);
    }
}
```